# Replace Nutone Door System with SIP

Tags: pjsip, pbx, sip-server, freepbx

I have an analog Nutone system that needs to be replaced. For each of three doors, it’s not possible to get an ethernet cable there. Looking for some sort of solution that would enable the usage of the existing 2-wire configuration. There is an existing PBX server I'd hope to integrate it with and existing WiFi phones that work well on that system. Anything that could call via WiFi and take power from the existing wiring would be idea.

Attempted to have electrician install ethernet wiring to each location and it wasn't possible due to the structure itself.

Comment: So what is question? Yes, it is likely possible. Need spend few days to determine what is wifi signal near it, if wires can send enough electricity, maybe add some lithium storage for prime-time etc.

Comment: Question is what device(s) would make this possible? Anything on the market or would it need to be custom built?

Comment: There are many possible solutions. But you probably need make some scheme to open door. There are many already built intercoms.

Comment: It doesn’t need to be able to open the door, just intercom via SIP (preferably with video). But I’m yet to find a device that doesn’t need a hardwired ethernet connection.

Comment: I think for you simpler just find SIP video intercom or phone with ethernet after that, use access point TPLINK N300 or similar. Unless you have decent budget or a lot of free time.

Comment: Sure but even then it gets sloppy having to inject PoE after the access point. With a theoretically unlimited budget and/or time what would be a better answer? Was thinking that something could probably be build on RasberryPi if there is a SIP library somewhere and then custom housing could be made pretty easily.

Comment: Unlimited - hire someone, use 2 wires for power deliver, put directional wifi antenna and create video phone with integrated wifi and external antenna. Add special port on phone for open door. Fastest development access point + video phone + setup on phone's intercome for open the door(or even remote ethernet switch - out of phone).

Answer (score 0):

I have used the axis I8016 doorbell cameras I have the unit tied in as a sip phone via my Asterisk/FreePBX as an extension and the camera tied into my ExacqVision CCTV server doing motion detection. using a linphone softphone app as the client so that the users can get the video feed from the doorbell. You need to turn on Video support in your sip settings in freepbx and I'm using the H264 codec. Other than that was just like setting up any other sip extension.

Comment: But how are you connecting it to your PBX server? Seems like it would need a hardwired network connection, no?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).